# cannot import name 'Job' from partially initialized module 'models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a Flask app but I'm receiving this error

ImportError: cannot import name 'Job' from partially initialized module 'models' (most likely due to a circular import)

This my code:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///jobs.db"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "your_secret_key"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    jobs = Job.query.all()
    return render_template("index.html", jobs=jobs)

from models import Job


class JobForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField("Job Title", validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField("Job Description", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Post Job")


@app.route("/post", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def post_job():
    form = JobForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        job = Job(title=form.title.data, description=form.description.data)
        db.session.add(job)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Job has been posted!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
    return render_template("post_job.html", title="Post Job", form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

models.py

```
from app import db


    class Job(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
        description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"Job('{self.title}', '{self.description}')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are using a circular import caused in`app.py` import db from models and in `models.py` import app.

You should move all connection 3rd app to another file like src/extension.py

**extension.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Now, another file will use db from this extension to avoid circular import.

**models.py:**

```
from extension import db

class Job(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
   description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    
   def __repr__(self):
       return f"Job('{self.title}', '{self.description}')"
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from extension import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///jobs.db"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "your_secret_key"

db.init_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```